# Exclude a specific method to be invoked by CDI Interceptor

Tags: java, ejb, cdi, interceptor

I have an interceptor binding annotation :

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyBinding {
}
```

To this CDI interceptor :

```
@Interceptor
@MyBinding 
public class MyInterceptor  {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object applyPolicy(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        return blablabla;
    }
}
```

And a class annotated, that mean every methods of this class will invoke MyInterceptor

```
@MyBinding
public class GlobalController {

    public void methodA() {...}
    public void methodB() {...}
}
```

All works fine, but I wish methodB not invoking my interceptor.

I tried both annotations [@ExcludeClassInterceptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/ExcludeClassInterceptors.html) and [@ExcludeDefaultInterceptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/ExcludeDefaultInterceptors.html) on my method but it doesn't works for me. I think these annotations are especially for exclude a method for EJB Interceptor, and not CDI Interceptor with Interceptor binding.

Comment: Hi, what CDI impl are you using?  What container?

Comment: Using Deltaspike in Jboss EAP 6.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about these annotations but as a workaround you can add an annotation to the method you want to exclude. Get `Method` from `InvocationContext` in the interceptor and check whether the method has the annotation. In this case just delegate to the original method.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@MyBinding` at method level:

```
public class GlobalController {

  @MyBinding    
  public void methodA() {...}

  public void methodB() {...}
}
```